# function returns tuple with nothing in it

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import os, sys

from time import strftime
from os.path import join

path = '/home/william/.btrfs-snapshots/'
age = 24
todaytuple = (int(strftime("%y")),int(strftime("%m"))int(strftime("%d")))



def get_date_tuple(filename):
    numberstr = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0')
    filename = ''
    datelist = []
    global datepart
    datepart = ''


    for i in filename:
        for n in numberstr:
            if i == n:
                datepart += i
                if len(datepart) == 2:
                    y = int(datepart)
                    datelist.append(y)
                    datepart = ''
            else:
                pass
    snapshotbirthtuple = tuple(datelist)
    return snapshotbirthtuple


for fname in os.listdir(path):
    snapshotbirthtupleinscope = get_date_tuple(fname)
    print(snapshotbirthtupleinscope)
    if snapshotbirthtupleinscope[0] <= todaytuple[0]:
```

`print(snapshotbirthtupleinscope)` prints `()` just empty parentheses,
i'm expecting a tuple of pairs of numbers.  i'm fairly certain that the function gives the right output, but i think i might not be passing the return variable correctly from the function.

```
() #the tuple returning nothing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./snapshotfinal.py", line 38, in <module>
    if snapshotbirthtupleinscope[0] <= todaytuple[0]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

why is snapshotbirthtupleinscope != snapshotbirthtuple?

Comment: `filename = ''` - why would you do that?

Comment: because it seemed to fix an error, i can't remember what the error was though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your could use some work.  First based on your variable names, you will want to assign something to filename for example:

```
filename = r"C:\MyFile.txt"
```

Once you have that, you will want to open the file and parse its contents:

```
 with open( filename, "r") as fp:
        data = fp.read()
        # Process Data In File where datelist is set
 # end with automatically closes file for you

 snapshotbirthtuple = tuple(datelist)
 return snapshotbirthtuple
```

The reason your original code returns no answer is because the line:

```
for i in filename:
```

filename is an empty string, there is nothing to iterate over, so there are never any values assigned to i.  As such your loop is skipped entirely so datelist never gets assigned

Comment: no, filename is supplied by `for fname in os.listdir(path):`, path is set in a piece i left out for brevity (which might not have been a good idea).

Comment: @william And then it's overwritten by the assignment `filename = ''` and is thus never used.